I can't send packets between my phone and esp32
I am trying to make a piece of code with android and python. Everything works between the android studio simulator and the esp32. Each device has a fixed IP address. However, with the phone (samsung A50), I can't send instructions to ESP32.
It tells me "NoRouteToHost". The ping from my computer to ESP32 works. Why doesn't it work with my phone (I use fun LiaisonP)? Please.
package com.example.a240922.viewmodel

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import io.ktor.network.selector.SelectorManager
import io.ktor.network.sockets.InetSocketAddress
import io.ktor.network.sockets.aSocket
import io.ktor.network.sockets.openWriteChannel
import io.ktor.util.cio.ChannelIOException
import io.ktor.utils.io.writeStringUtf8
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Job
import kotlinx.coroutines.Runnable
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.request.HttpRequestBuilder
import io.ktor.client.request.get
import io.ktor.client.request.host
import io.ktor.client.request.url
import io.ktor.client.statement.HttpResponse
import kotlinx.coroutines.async


class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {
    val thread = ThreadMain()


    fun offLiaison() {
        val runnable = LiaisonP()
        val rthread = Thread(runnable)
        rthread.start()
        }



//    var mycoroutine: Job = Job()
    fun onLiaison(){
        val runnable = LiaisonAlpha()
        val myThread = Thread(runnable)
        myThread.start()

    }

}

class ThreadMain() : Thread(){
    override fun run() {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val selectorManager = SelectorManager(Dispatchers.IO)
            val socket = aSocket(selectorManager).tcp().connect("ricklin.ddns.net", 8080)
            val sendChannel = socket.openWriteChannel(autoFlush = true)
            //val myMessage = readln()
            var myMessage: String = "Hello"
            sendChannel.writeStringUtf8("Hello")
            socket.close()
            selectorManager.close()
            println("fin de mon thread")
            //super.run()
        }
    }
}

suspend fun sendLiaison(){
    val selectorManager = SelectorManager(Dispatchers.IO)
    val socket = aSocket(selectorManager).tcp().connect("192.168.1.43", 8080)
    val sendChannel = socket.openWriteChannel(autoFlush = true)
    val myMessage = readln()
    sendChannel.writeStringUtf8("$myMessage\n")
    socket.close()
    selectorManager.close()

}

class LiaisonP : Runnable{
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.IO)

    override fun run() {
        val job = scope.async {
            try {
                val addr = "/Alvik"

                val selectorManager = SelectorManager(Dispatchers.IO)
                val socket = aSocket(selectorManager).tcp().connect("192.168.1.43", 80)
                val sendChannel = socket.openWriteChannel(autoFlush = true)
                //val myMessage = readln()
                var myMessage: String = "Hello"
                sendChannel.writeStringUtf8("{\"action\":\"forward\"}")
                socket.close()
                selectorManager.close()
                println("fin de mon thread")
            }catch (e:Exception){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

    }
}

class LiaisonAlpha : Runnable{
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.IO)
    override fun run() {
        val job = scope.launch {
            val client = HttpClient()
            val response: HttpResponse = client.get("http://192.168.1.43"){
                url{
                    parameters.append("action","forward")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NEARBY_WIFI_DEVICES"
        android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme._240922"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme._240922">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

I tried adding permissions, changing ports, modifying the routine.

Are you able to connect with the Android client sockets (https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket)? Also, you can try port forwarding (https://developer.android.com/tools/adb#forwardports).
